# mandrill web hooks failing due to ssl ca issue

Tags: php, ssl, https, mandrill

i'm using mandrill and setting up webhooks is failing.  i moved my domain to a new server and set up ssl again.

now when i look at the web hooks admin page i see this error: 
- Error: POST to https://my.website.com/hooks/mandrill.php failed: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

when i try to change the url for this webhook, all i get is 
 - We can't verify that the URL exists. More info

when i contacted mandrill support they suggested that it may be missing intermediate CA for my SSL cert.  That browsers wouldn't care but the server did care and would fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this url helped me figure out that indeed my intermediate CA was not installed 
- https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

ends up i didn't have the intermediate CA enabled in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.  the lines were commented out.  i removed the comments and restarted apache and all is working well now.

i could save the changed webhook and when i clicked send test it sent them.  however there still was a stale error on the webhook about the ssl issue.  but it was no longer preventing me from editting or sending webhooks

hope this saves someone else some time

Comment: I encountered this problem too, can you explain which line did you uncomment, I can't find that line but I already add SSLCaCertificateFile in my virtual host